# Simple Roda app with routes in separate files

Tags: ruby, roda

I'm trying to learn Roda and am having a bit of trouble moving into a style of separating out routes into their own files. I got the simple app from the Roda README running and am working on that as a base.

I am trying to use the multi_route plugin as well. So far, this is my setup:

## config.ru

```
require 'rack/unreloader'
Unreloader = Rack::Unreloader.new { Greeter }
require 'roda'
Unreloader.require './backend.rb'
run Unreloader
```

## backend.rb

```
require 'roda'
# Class Roda app
class Greeter < Roda
  puts 'hey'
  plugin :multi_route

  puts 'hey hey hey'
  route(&:multi_route)
end

Dir['./routes/*.rb'].each { |f| require f }
```

## index.rb

```
Greeter.route '/' do |r|
  r.redirect 'hello'
end
```

## hello.rb

```
Greeter.route '/hello' do |r|
  r.on 'hello' do
    puts 'hello'
    @greeting = 'helloooooooo'

    r.get 'world' do
      @greeting = 'hola'
      "#{@greeting} world!"
    end

    r.is do
      r.get do
        "#{@greeting}!"
      end

      r.post do
        puts "Someone said #{@greeting}!"
        r.redirect
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, now when I do my rackup config.ru and go to localhost:9292 in my browser, I get a blank page and 404s in the console. What is out of place? I suspect I'm not using multi_route correctly, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo in here or in your app, but you're requiring `backend.rb` -- `Unreloader.require './backend.rb'` -- but you've labeled the file here as `backend.ru`

Comment: Typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `multi_run` plugin:

*routes/foo.rb*

```rb
module Routes
  class Foo < Roda
    route do |r|
      r.get do
        "hello foo"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*routes/bar.rb*

```rb
module Routes
  class Bar < Roda
    route do |r|
      r.get do
        "hello bar"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*config.ru*

```rb
require "roda"

Dir['routes/*.rb'].each { |f| require_relative f }

class App < Roda
  plugin :multi_run # Allow to group many "r.run" in one call

  run 'foo', Routes::Foo # match /foo
  run 'bar', Routes::Bar # match /bar

  # Same as
  # route do |r| 
  #   r.multi_run
  # end
  route(&:multi_run)
end

run App.freeze.app
```

For more alternatives:

- https://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/conventions_rdoc.html
- https://github.com/jeremyevans/roda#label-Composition

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old, but maybe it will be useful for someone later on.

For Roda, forward slashes are significant. In your example, `Greeter.route '/hello' do |r|` matches `localhost:9292//hello`, and not `localhost:9292/hello`.

You probably want the following:

```
Greeter.route do |r|
  r.redirect 'hello'
end
```

And also this. That nested `r.on 'hello' do` meant that that branch of the tree only matched `localhost:9292/hello/hello` and `localhost:9292/hello/hello/world`, that is probably not what you wanted.

```
Greeter.route 'hello' do |r|
  puts 'hello'
  @greeting = 'helloooooooo'

  r.get 'world' do
    @greeting = 'hola'
    "#{@greeting} world!"
  end

  r.is do
    r.get do
      "#{@greeting}!"
    end

    r.post do
      puts "Someone said #{@greeting}!"
      r.redirect
    end
  end
end
```